# Web scraping for the ASOS product-price using Python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape product data from the ASOS E-commerce site.I am using python and Beautifulsoup .I have been able to scrape most of the data I need **except the price**.I need help on how to target the price.This is the page I am scraping from https://www.asos.com/asos-design/asos-design-lambswool-crew-neck-jumper-in-wine/prd/14801727?colourwayid=16645056&SearchQuery=&cid=7617 .I have the page html code on a separate html file that am filtering from.
I have tried this

```
product_data['price'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"grid-row rendered"}).find('span', {"class":"current-price-container"}).find('span',{"class":"current-price"}).text
```

but I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Test.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html
def Ecom_Scraper():
    #get html input
    with open("temp.html", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    html_content = f.read()
    html_content = html.unescape(html_content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
    product_data={}

    product_data['title'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"product-hero"}).find('h1').text
    product_data['code'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"product-code"}).find('p').text
    product_data['description'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"product- 
     description"}).find('ul').text
    product_data['brand'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"brand-description"}).find('p').text
    product_data['aboutme'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"about-me"}).find('p').text
    product_data['lookatme'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"care-info"}).find('p').text

    print(product_data)
Ecom_Scraper()
```

This is the code for my project views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, redirect, 
get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404,HttpResponseRedirect
import requests
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import serializers

class GetProductDetail(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
    html_content = request.data.get('product_data')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.unescape(html_content), 'html.parser')
    product_data = {}
    product_data['title'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"product-hero"}).find('h1').text
    product_data['code'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"product-code"}).find('p').text
    product_data['description'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"product-description"}).find('ul').text
    product_data['brand'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"brand-description"}).find('p').text
    product_data['aboutme'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"about-me"}).find('p').text
    product_data['lookatme'] = soup.find('div', {"class":"care-info"}).find('p').text

    product_json = json.dumps(product_data, indent=4)
    print(product_json)
    return Response({product_json})
```

Answer (score 0):

The price is loaded dynamically, so you won't see it using `BeautifulSoup`.

Also, are you loading the website from a local drive? If so, you're making a mistake because this is *not* what you're going to get when requesting for the `HTML` from the server.

Anyhow, here's how to get the basic product data and its price:

```
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"
}

product_url = "https://www.asos.com/asos-design/asos-design-lambswool-crew-neck-jumper-in-wine/prd/14801727"
page = requests.get(product_url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser").find("script", type="application/ld+json")
product_data = json.loads(soup.string)

print(product_data["name"], product_data["color"], product_data["productID"])


price_endpoint = f"https://www.asos.com/api/product/catalogue/v3/stockprice?productIds={product_data['productID']}&store=COM&currency=GBP"

print(requests.get(price_endpoint, headers=headers).json()[0]["productPrice"]["xrp"]["text"])
```

This prints:

```
ASOS DESIGN lambswool crew neck jumper in wine Wine 14801727
£35.00
```

Comment: .I converted the page code to a json object and load it from my local drive.But this is just for faster testing.Let me study your solution and revert

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution into my code but I am having a few challenges. I have added my views.py above.Kindly take some time to advise.I will really appreciate